# Turn The Gun On Somebody

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a separate question about the phrase "*turn the* ***gun*** *on somebody*" and "*turn the* ***knife*** *on somebody*".  It seems that, according to google, "*turn the* ***gun*** *on somebody*" is more common than "*turn the* ***knife*** *on somebody*".  Could it be that because a gun could be "theoretically" turned on, but a knife cannot be "*turned on*", that "*turn the knife on somebody*" is  idiomatically wrong?

Comment: I know neither expression. Where did you find them?

Comment: What @tunny said. What specific *meaning* do you have in mind here? I'd hardly call it an idiom with the same status as, say, *turn the **tables** on someone*, or *turn the **spotlight** on them*.

Comment: I've heard "turn the gun on himself/herself" before. It is used to express suicide by gun and only in this exact usage. I've never seen "turn the knife".

Comment: I could see it being used this way though, the 'revolving door effect' Someone did something and it is coming back to them (maybe even worse.) That's what it looks like but I can't say its common or even understood in the way I described.

Comment: It simply means that a gun is pointed in a new direction. _Joe Dark shot FumbleFingers and Tunny between the eyes then slowly turned the gun on Meatie._  Never heard of _Turn the knife on somebody_ however.

Comment: @JoeDark that answer works but the question is about idioms not literal usage.

Comment: **turn** (*v.*) - change or cause to change direction; aim, point, or direct (something). This has nothing to do with turning a gun on or off.

Answer (score 1):

No. "Turned on" does not refer to the state of the weapon, at least not in the sense of "activated" (which is my interpretation of your question, correct me if I'm wrong). As Joe Dark commented above, all it means is that the weapon is directed at a different target; it could work for any weapon, it's just most commonly used with firearms.

I'm familiar with the term and have seen it used for both knife and gun (and I'm a little surprised that others haven't- I'm American, if that matters). The connotation is that the weapon is used on or directed at one target, and the wielder then uses it on or directs it at another target.

[Here is another ELL example using "body-building equipment," a usage which I confess I *had* not seen before.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38877/turn-equipment-on-somebody)